# How to set the dynamic style with the click in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Now, there are two items. A left item and a right item. I want to realize a result.

The first render, the left item is active, the right item is not active. When I click the right item. The right item is active, the left item is not active.
 When I click the left item. The left item is active, the right item is not active.

If the item is active, text in the item is blue, the bottom line is green.
If the item is not active, text in the item is black, the bottom line is none.

Now my code works like image below.

[image]

My code is below:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes}   from "react";

import {
  View,
  Image,
  Text,
  ListView,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
}   from 'react-native';

const ItemView = ({title, onPress}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');

class MyOrder extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  showService = () =>{
    console.log('click Left');
  }

  showReport = () => {
    console.log('click Right')
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <ItemView title="left" onPress={this.showService}/>
            <ItemView title="right" onPress={this.showReport}/>
          </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    flex:1,
    width:'100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 16,

  },
  activeItem: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#1bbc9b',
  },
  itemTitle: {
    color: '#44c0fe',
    fontWeight:'900',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  content: {
    height:48,
    flexDirection:'row',
    width: width,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent:'space-around',
  },
});

export default  MyOrder;
```

How to use combine style to realize it?  For example, `style = {[styles.item, styles.activeItem]}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of which tab is active in the parent component:

```
const ItemView = ({title, onPress, isActive}) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={[
          styles.itemTitle, 
          isActive ? styles.activeItem : null,
        ]}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

class MyOrder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeTab: 'left',
    }
  }

  showService = () =>{
    console.log('click Left');
    this.setState({activeTab: 'left'});
  }

  showReport = () => {
    console.log('click Right')
    this.setState({activeTab: 'right'});
  }

  render() {
    const isActive = (tab) => this.state.activeTab === tab; 
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <ItemView title="left" onPress={this.showService} isActive={isActive('left')} />
            <ItemView title="right" onPress={this.showReport} isActive={isActive('right')} />
          </View>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  item: {
    flex:1,
    width:'100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 16,

  },
  activeItem: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#1bbc9b',
    color: '#44c0fe',
  },
  itemTitle: {
    color: 'black',
    fontWeight:'900',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  content: {
    height:48,
    flexDirection:'row',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent:'space-around',
  },
});
```